# Retrieving different on year using php

Tags: php

Sorry, I am very new to PHP. I searched for similar problems on Google, but they say it should be no problem if using PHP version 5.2+. I don't know what version that I am using right now. The error message shows like this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff() in line 3 at $interval

If I comment-out lines 3 and 4, it can run, but can't retrieve a different date. I only want the year only. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is? Thanks in advance.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("$bday"); 
$date2 = new DateTime("now"); 
$interval = $date1->diff($date2); 
$diff = $interval->format('%y-%m-%d'); 
$dif2 = explode("-",$diff);

$umur = $dif2[0];
if($umur < 10){ $catumur = 1; }
if(($umur > 9)&&($umur < 20)){ $catumur = 2; }
if(($umur > 19)&&($umur < 60)){ $catumur = 3; }
if($umur > 59){ $catumur = 4; }
```

Comment: Do you have access to the command line; or possibly your version is displayed in the page headers? Response header under `X-Powered-By`.

Comment: [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) was introduced on PHP 5.3. `DateTime` was buggy on PHP 5.3. Upgrade to the most recent version (PHP 7.0 or, at least, PHP 5.6).

Comment: (http://s15.postimg.org/6fcnlg47v/Capture.jpg)..how to change these coding to PHP ver5.2.9? if i upgrade latest version of PHP, I afraid another browser not support them. maybe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. To check the version of your PHP, Create a php file and inside it, use `phpinfo()`. Run it and it will show all the details of your PHP.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
```

[image]

Comment: [link] (http://s15.postimg.org/6fcnlg47v/Capture.jpg)
i dont know to upload image..sorry. the link could help.
i dont have any idea.

Comment: I see. Best thing to do, As commented by axiac to your post, Try to upgrade the version of your PHP to atleast 5.6 to avoid encountering those bugs, that version is stable.

Comment: @mondesilva..i afraid another browser not support them.

Comment: @ZackZeidy, Browser Support? No. PHP is a back end process (Server Side), No matter what browser (or version of it) it is, it will work.

Comment: @mondesilva, Now i'm using XAMPP. If i want upgrade PHP version, is it upgrade xampp or PHP only? Sorry for silly question. I'm new.

Comment: @ZackZeidy, You can upgrade PHP only. Follow this [instructions](http://www.techflirt.com/how-to-upgrade-php-in-xampp/)